# How boundingRect() works

Tags: c++, qwt, rectangles

I have some code where I draw a symbol and attach it to a plot. Now I want to find out whether there is a bounding rectangle automatically created with the symbol so that I can write some code to select the symbol so that users can edit it - select it in order to delete it for example.

I have seen a boundingRect() method in qwt_plot_marker.h, how would I use this to determine whether there is a rectangle created when the following code is implemented?

```
void DataPointMarker::draw(QPainter *p, 
const QwtScaleMap &xMap, const QwtScaleMap &yMap,
const QRect &) const
{
  const int posX = xMap.transform(m_positionX);
  const int posY = yMap.transform(m_positionY);

p->save();

symbol().draw(p, posX, posY);

p->restore();
```

The symbol is defined elsewhere. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not too familiar with the qt classes, maybe [this](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qgraphicsitem.html#boundingRect) helps?

Comment: This is what I was looking at before I asked the question but I can't make any sense of it.

Answer (score 2):

The [boundingRect](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/class_qwt_series_data.html#aedb969ba51a27d88d26ad7f7cb1c2c7f) function returns a rectangle large enough that all points of a series fit into it. This is needed for autoscaling and definately not what you are looking for. What you want is something like a focus or selection indicator. You may take a look into the `event_filter` example shipped with qwt. There it is possible to select and move points/markers.

The qwt example directoy can be found in the base directory of qwt (at least on Windows), for example `qwt-6.0\examples`. The binaries are located in `qwt-6.0\examples\bin`. Take a look into the `INSTALL` file to see how to build the binaries.

Comment: Alright, I will give it a try. May you provide a link to the example - if there is one - or direct me to where I can find it please? Thanks.